# Power Automate - send an email notification is not working

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate, email-notifications

I tried to make a flow that sends mail when the item is added to the list, but I get the error in the picture. I tried the solutions he gave me, but it didn't work.
[image: The error is in this picture]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do anything else than the error recommends. If you really need the 'Send an email notification' action (with all its limitations) then contact Microsoft support, otherwise use the Outlook 365 action 'Send an email (V2)'.

[image]

Comment: How can i use "Send an email (V2)"? I can only see send an email v3.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot above.